# OR operator for JSOUP select() method

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to find all `<div class="name1">` or `<div class="name2">` tags in one page/document.

How can I use `OR` operator in `doc.select("div.name1 OR div.name2")`?

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The [select method of JSoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) implements more or less the CSS selector syntax. So you can very simply use the CSS way of specifying alternatives, i.e. using `,`. This should work:

```
doc.select("div.name1,div.name2");
```